# javascript datastructures: priority queue, dictionary, balanced binary tree?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Is there a javascript library that provides common data structures, e.g. priority queue, dictionary, and successor queries (balanced trees)? I could roll my own, but I'd rather have a black-box, especially if it's already been "optimized".

Comment: You can use Javascript array as dictionary. I think JS engine implementation should optimize the operations to some degree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript data structures library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909452/javascript-data-structures-library)

Comment: @nhahtdh: Why an array? A normal `Object` works just fine.

Comment: @icktoofay: I think you are right. I'm still quite novice with JS.

Comment: @icktoofay yup. it's a duplicate. I swear I did look before I posted the question, so I'm not sure why I wasn't seeing that one... thanks for the reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript data structures library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909452/javascript-data-structures-library)

Answer (score 1):

Google's Closure Library should have most of what you need:
https://developers.google.com/closure/library/

Answer (score -1):

use below lib of already implemented collection classes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/collectiondatalib

Examples:

const lib = require('collectiondatalib') 
 lib.Search.binary_search([1,2,3,4,5], 5)

4

lib.Sort.bubble_sort([3,5,1,4,2])

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

lib.Sort.merge_sort([3,5,1,4,2])

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

let list = new lib.SinglyLinkedList()

list.push(12) list.push(13) list.push(14) console.log(list)

SinglyLinkedList { head: Node { val: 12, next: Node { val: 13, next: 
 [Node] } }, tail: Node { val: 14, next: null }, length: 3 }

`let queue=new lib.PriorityQueue()`
 `queue.enqueue("hello",5)`
 `queue.enqueue("hi",4)`

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Added examples how to use this lib