# Specialized LinkedLists in JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have used Java's built-in APIs for data structures and Google Guava's additions to the API but JavaScript's support for data structures seems to be rather weak. If I need to use advanced data structures for JS, is there any library that I can include in my project?

Comment: Check this for some ideas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909452/javascript-data-structures-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library [collectionsjs](http://www.collectionsjs.com/) contains a [list](http://www.collectionsjs.com/list) implementation, which is "backed by a doubly linked list with a head node".

```js
var list = new List([1, 2, 3]);
list.splice(1, 1, 6, 5);
alert(list.toArray());
// [1,6,5,3]
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/montagejs/collections/master/collections.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```